# Codenameone Detect keyboard showing

Tags: codenameone

Is there a way to add a listener on the Form for when the virtual keyboard shows or dissapears in Codenameone?

The reason is because I want to detect this and recalculate the size of the Form. Currently, the `sizeChangedListener` does not get called when the keyboard shows, and so some components are hidden from view, as I can't recalculate the sizes of the components.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't do that.

Keyboards resize the UI only on Android and don't have that affect on iOS/Windows. We will probably change that behavior on Android as well so relying on it in that way doesn't make sense.

Size changed is called on the form when running on Android otherwise basic stuff wouldn't work. Notice that you **shouldn't** rely on it for typical code, if you use scrollable containers properly and the right layout things should automatically rearrange themselves correctly.

I suggest rephrasing the question with a sample of your UI/layout and problems including screenshots. E.g. a common issue is placing a text field within a non-scrollable container so the resize logic can't do anything and it fails by making the text disappear.

Answer (score 1):

See Display.getInstance().setVirtualKeyboardListener(...)